# Text input like evernote's in Android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext, evernote

What do I have to use to create a text input like evernote's?

It's look like they are using two edittext to create this, but even if I can have the same style for the upper part (whith one edittext), I don't know how to do the bottom part: it's look like the edittext is divided in two part, and the bottom part is taking the full screen.

Do I have to create some custom view?

[image: Evernote edittext]

Comment: It's what I said^^ Either they are using 2 edittext, and I don't know how to do design it like that, either they created a customview to have this aspect. In both case, I don't know how they did that.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. There are three main elements.

- **EditText** with specified height (18sp for example) and width match_parent,
- no padding/margin, 1dp height, match_parent width **View** element,
- **EditText** with no padding/margin, width match_parent, specified height (36sp for example)

They also use hint option to display text in **EditText**, and View background color same as hint text color.